# remove link when checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I have a table with Datatable plugin, and I did the part when the user clicks on the row (`tr`) that he will be redirected to that link. but i don't want the user to be redirected to the link when he clicks the checkbox on the row.
Here is the html:

```
 <tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td class="number_elem_lang">
      <label class='with-square-checkbox2-mylist-details'>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <span></span>
      </label>
   </td>
   <td class=""> ID022ox</td>
   <td class="list-name">First Lipsum List</td>
   <td class=""> 22 Candidates</td>
   <td class="">01 Apr 2016</td>
   <td><a href=""></a></td>
</tr>
```

Here is my javascript code for redirecting the user to the link when it's clicked:

```
$('#sample_1').on( 'click', 'tr', function() {
  var $a = $(this).find('a').last();
  if ( $a.length )
     window.location = $a.attr('href');
  } );
```

So i don't want to redirect the user when the checkbox is clicked, pls help :)

Thank you

Comment: just comment out the line which redirecting

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `e.target` to check what element the user clicked on. In the example below, we check if the user clicked on an `input` of type `checkbox`. Then we don't run the rest of the function.

```js
$('table').on( 'click', 'tr', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);
    debugger; // For debugging purposes.
    if (target.is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
        // Do not continue if it's an input
        console.log('no redirect');
        return true;
    }
    console.log('do redirect');
    var $a = $(this).find('a').last();
    if ( $a.length )
       window.location = $a.attr('href');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr class="odd gradeX">
   <td class="number_elem_lang">
      <label class='with-square-checkbox2-mylist-details'>
      <input type='checkbox'>
      <span></span>
      </label>
   </td>
   <td class=""> ID022ox</td>
   <td class="list-name">First Lipsum List</td>
   <td class=""> 22 Candidates</td>
   <td class="">01 Apr 2016</td>
   <td><a href=""></a></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Update:**

In this particular case the checkbox had some custom styling, which led to `e.target` being a `span`. The solution is to change the condition to `$(e.target).is('span')`, or even better set a class on the `span` and use `$(e.target).hasClass('my-custom-checkbox')`.

Comment: You should explain a little bit but yes... I would do that too ! Stopping the propagation could be interesting too (even if it is not needed here)

Comment: Hmm, it doesnt work, is this something with the datatables plugin that doesn't allow this. I'm using all of your code :/

Comment: What's happening then? Doesn't it recognize the `target`as input?

Comment: ` $('#sample_1').on( 'click', 'tr', function(e) {
                    var target = $(e.target);
                    if (target.is('input[type=checkbox]')) {
                        // Do not continue if it's an input
                        console.log('no redirect');
                        return true;
                    }
                    console.log('do redirect');
                    var $a = $(this).find('a').last();
                    if ( $a.length )
                       window.location = $a.attr('href');
                    
                  } ); `

Comment: this is what im using, i really don't know but it is not working, it still redirect to the link

Comment: Can you debug using the console and check what `$(e.target)` is?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118625/discussion-between-smoksnes-and-muli).

Comment: through the chat @smoksnes helped me, i used this if condition  `if($(e.target).is('label') || $(e.target).is('input[type=checkbox]') || $(e.target).is('span'))`

Answer (score 1):

Here you go - Add this to cancel the event when the checkbox is clicked:

```
 $("tr input:checkbox").click(function(event) {
     event.stopPropagation();
     // Do something
 });
```

Here is a working Demo

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var $a = $(this).find('a').last();
  if ($a.length)
    alert("fsfsd");
});

$("tr input:checkbox").click(function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  // Do something
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr class="odd gradeX">
    <td class="number_elem_lang">
      <label class='with-square-checkbox2-mylist-details'>
        <input type='checkbox'>
        <span></span>
      </label>
    </td>
    <td class="">ID022ox</td>
    <td class="list-name">First Lipsum List</td>
    <td class="">22 Candidates</td>
    <td class="">01 Apr 2016</td>
    <td>
      <a href=""></a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: this isn't really helpful

Comment: please explain to me why

Answer (score 0):

Use the if construction

```
if ($('input.checkbox_check').is(':checked')) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Add a class named yourradio in your radio button and add this javascript 
<label class='with-square-checkbox2-mylist-details'>
      <input type='checkbox' class="yourradio">
      <span></span>
      </label> 
<script>
$('.yourradio').on('click', function(){
 return false;
});
```

Comment: this doesn't help, cus then my checkbox won't check